# returning AccessDenied in taskscheduler(boot trigger) and need run without uac?

Tags: c++, triggers, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to write the boot trigger, but the project gives me an Access Denied error.

When I run the code in administrator level the task is created, but without this, it shows the same error.

```
ITrigger *pTrigger = NULL;
    hr = pTriggerCollection->Create(TASK_TRIGGER_BOOT, &pTrigger);
    pTriggerCollection->Release();
IBootTrigger *pBootTrigger = NULL;
    hr = pTrigger->QueryInterface(IID_IBootTrigger, (void**)&pBootTrigger);
    pTrigger->Release();

    IRegisteredTask *pRegisteredTask = NULL;
    hr = pRootFolder->RegisterTaskDefinition(_bstr_t(wszTaskName), pTask, TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE, _variant_t(), _variant_t(), TASK_LOGON_INTERACTIVE_TOKEN, _variant_t(L""), &pRegisteredTask);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return FALSE;
    }
```